# SVN: Skip a single file only in the working copy

Tags: svn, netbeans

I want to skip a file which has IDE-specific settings in it when committing with Netbeans. It should only be skipped in some working copies where I have special settings applied. The other working copies should commit it, so that the project is working correctly on checkout with Netbeans.

It is not an option to ignore this file with the svn:ignore option for the folder containing it because this file should only be skipped in this working copy. If it would be possible to set the svn:ignore option on this file instance directly, this would be what I want, but it is only possible to set it on the folder.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that as svn-ignore is a repository level setting (an svn property which, when committed, is stored in the repository).

One solution might be to rename the base config file to *filename.ext*.template, commit that, and svn ignore the config file. Developers who check the folder out will have to make their config file by copying the template.

Alternatively, leave the most useful config in svn and don't commit changes to that file from "special case" working copies.

Comment: "don't commit changes to that file from "special case" working copies." But you also know no way to tell Netbeans to omit the file so that it would be automated? Your suggestion works, but the uncomfortable thing is that I can not commit the whole project at ones then.